# How to reference the internal elements of a two columns result from a query in order to use them in a calculated column?

Tags: obiee

When I click year prompt, It must display both current year along with previous 2 years revenue in OBI 12c (Analysis).

For example when I click 2019 in prompt, It must display 2017,2018 and 2019's revenue.

I use the following code to do this:

```
"Time"."Year" >= @{pv_Year}{2019} - 2 AND "Time"."Year" <= @{pv_Year}{2019}
```

And it displays this:

```
2017            2018           2019
Revenue         Revenue        Revenue
```

But I also need to create two calculated columns with the following:

```
**Colum1:** %Var_2017_2018                                    
**Formula:** (2017 Revenue - 2018 Revenue)/2018 Revenue       

**Colum1:** %var_2018_2019
**Formula:**   (2018 Revenue - 2019 Revenue)/2019 Revenue
```

How Can I do this?

Is it posible to do it with OBI Analysis?

Comment: This is a kind of unclear question.
Do you mean to use your prompt value (the value is passed by clicking prompt) in edit formula of your column?

Comment: I want to use the report result columns to build a calculated column, that is, the revenue of 2017 and the revenue of 2018